# How do I convert an OsString to a u16 on POSIX systems?

Tags: string, rust, type-conversion, integer, posix

I'm grabbing a string from the environment via `std::env::var_os`, and I want to attempt to convert the resulting `OsString` received from matching the returned `Option<OsString>` into a `u16`. How could I go about doing this in a way that works on POSIX systems?

Comment: Why are you using `var_os` instead of `var`? Are you intending to handle non-UTF-8 environment variables?

Comment: @Shepmaster Good question! I read that it returns `None` if the variable isn't set, which I liked as that's exactly what I wanted, but now I see `var` does not force me to deal with the OsString stuff. Hmm.

Comment: `var` returns an error if it’s missing or invalid, which you can change into an `Option` with `.ok()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to convert an `Option<OsString>` to an `Option<u16>` you can use this function:

```rust
use std::ffi::OsString;

fn to_integer(maybe_os_string: Option<OsString>) -> Option<u16> {
    if let Some(os_string) = maybe_os_string {
        if let Ok(string) = os_string.into_string() {
            if let Ok(integer) = string.parse::<u16>() {
                return Some(integer);
            }
        }
    }
    None
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=44c7b4e98bfcf19889b2ab2b100282c9)

It should work regardless of underlying operating system. The caller of the function would have to handle the `None` case if the `OsString` can't be parsed as a `u16`.

Comment: Since `Option` works with `?` you can avoid the nesting with `maybe_os_string?.into_string().ok()?.parse::<u16>().ok()`.

Comment: If you are going to use `into_string`, you might as well use `env::var` instead of `env::var_os`.

Comment: Or `maybe_os_string.and_then (|s| s.into_string().ok()).and_then (|s| s.parse::<u16>().ok())`